# Form Partial Differential Equation

Tags: partial-derivative

z=A exp(pt) sin (px)

Form pde for the above equation where A and p are arbitrary constants

x ,t independent variable
Z = f(x,t)

Answer (score 1):

$$Z(x,t)=Ae^{pt}\sin(px)$$
$$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}=pZ$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial x^2}=-p^2Z$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}\right)^2=-Z\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial x^2}$$

Comment: Thank You Jacquelin, I have a query, as there are 2 arbitrary constants so the order should be 1 . But after forming Differential equation order comes out to be 2. Can you explain on this.

Comment: This is a PDE, not an ODE. Why the order should be 1 ? This is not a requirement included in the wording of the question. The solutions of a linear second order PDE are the linear combinations of two independent functions, not of only two constants. Moreover, the proposed PDE is not linear. As requested, $Z=Ae^{pt}\sin(px)$ is a solution of $\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}\right)^2=-Z\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial x^2}$ . But not a unique solution of course.

Comment: Thank you Jacquelin. 2 arbitrary constants = 2 independent variables , so the solution should be unique i.e. 1 pde is only possible. Order=no. of arbitrary constants–1, so the order should be 1. This is my understanding. Please can you explain on this.

Comment: The solution of any PDE is never unique if no boundary condition is specified. I suppose that there is an ambiguity in the wording of your question.

Comment: In your question you specify nothing about order of PDE and nothing about unicity. So, my answer is correct since $Z(x,t)=Ae^{pt}\sin(px)$ is a solution of $\left(\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}\right)^2=-Z\frac{\partial^2 Z}{\partial x^2}$ as expected.

Comment: Thank you Jacquelin fir your efforts.

Comment: I was just having some doubt . I will come back to you once again with another problem. Thank you Jacquelin once again